# How did they design this ? How should my data look like?

Tags: charts

[image: sample chart]

How did they design this ? How should my data look like? 
Can excel count so many variables ?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a [**stacked bar chart**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/03/understanding-stacked-bar-charts/). You can [do this in Excel](https://www.smartsheet.com/stacked-bar-chart-graph#how-do-you-make-a-stacked-bar-chart-in-excel) for sure, or you can use tools such as [Google bar charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#stacked-bar-charts) if you need to display the graphs online